# Installing Ubuntu Studio applications and performance (kernel) without changing my current Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-studio

I currently am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with unity and I found Ubuntu Studio to be quite appealing. I am looking for an easy way to install all the Ubuntu Studio applications and performance enhancers without needing to install it from scratch. Is there an easy way to do this? I found a forum post that simply suggested to install ubuntustudio-audio and other application packages, but I do not think this includes any of the enhanced settings present in Ubuntu Studio. 
Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu Studio packages manually or with synaptic package manager. Official instructions are here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation

I recommend you to install Synaptic Package Manager (from "software" aplication on system category in the ubuntu menu), and search there ALL "ubuntustudio" packages, mark them for installation, and apply changes.  It's 1GB to download.
Lowlatency kernel will not be installed, you'll have to select it in Synaptic if you want lowlatency or realtime kernels.

I'm currently running this setup (Ubuntu 16.04 with Ubuntu Studio installed as a package) but I'm still doing its "fine tuning".  And I have to give you an advice: once you install Ubuntu Studio and log in to Ubuntu studio desktop session (wich is based on XFCE desktop), do not try to edit Ubuntu Menu with right click, it opens MenuLibre menu editor wich will literally screw up your menu.  Edit your menu by using application "Alacarte" instead of Menulibre.  Everything else seems to work smooth by now.

Comment: Hope you enjoy Ubuntu Studio, it rocks.  Maybe one day you'll find yourself answering other user's questions.